# Heat Absorption of Liquids

Tags: everyday-chemistry

Does same amount of heat absorbed cause the same changes of temperature in the same amount of different liquids? Explain.

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! For formatting help visit the [help] center and for more information about this page, take the [tour]. Your question is phrased a lot like a homework question. Homework questions should show the work or thinking that you have already done in an initial attempt to answer the question. For help asking a good homework question, see: [How do I ask homework questions on Chemistry Stack Exchange](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange)?

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

To answer your question we will assume certain things here.

1. Assume  $C_p = C_v$ for most liquids, where $C_p$ is the heat capacity at constant pressure, and $C_v$ is the heat capacity at constant volume.
2. Assume that $C$ is constant with respect to temperature, which is not the case in most real fluids. Here, in order to leave out the integration, we assume that it is a constant.

Then,

$Q = C\Delta{}T$

As different liquids have different heat capacities, the same amount of heat supplied to the liquid would result in a different $\Delta{}T$, the temperature change.

The higher the heat capacity, the more heat is required to raise a unit mass(or mole) of substance  by a unit temperature. Likewise, more heat has to be removed from the unit mass of substance in order to decrease the temperature by a unit temperature.

In other words, the higher the heat capacity, the more "reluctant" it is to change its temperature, for the same amount of heat supplied.

Comment: As examples, water has a heat capacity of 75 J/mol (to raise by 1 degree), while methanol is